# Issue with a regex to validate the Nigerian phone numbering system

Tags: php, regex, pcre, phone-number

I’m working on a regex to match this set of numbers:

```
xxxx xxx xxxx
01 xxx xxxx
+234 1 xxx xxxx
xxxx-xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
234 xxx xxx xxxx
234(xxx)xxx-xxxx
234(xxx)xxx xxxx
+234(xxx)xxx xxxx
+234(xxx) xxx xxxx
+234(xxx)xxx-xxxx
234xxxxxxxxxx
+234xxxxxxxxxx
```

The rules are:

- At most 11 digits long (any number combo, excluding the static parts)
- Optional (234) or (+234)
- Optional 1 or 01 or 234 1
- Optional bracketing as specified above.

It’s to validate the Nigerian phone numbering system. I have searched far and wide and haven’t seen any good solutions so far.

I have this expression:

```
/^(\+)?234[0-9]*?.*/gm
```

but it doesn’t match the ones without (234) properly.

Specifically:

```
xxxx xxx xxxx
01 xxx xxxx
xxxx-xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

How can I make this work? I’m kinda new to regex, would appreciate any assistance I can get.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1099Nr/1)

Comment: The length of your examples is often not 11 digits. What should we do with that?

Comment: At most 11 digits long (any number combo, excluding the static parts) — edited

Comment: It is still not clear, which means, I (or, I believe anyone) cannot give a definitive answer. Try https://regex101.com/r/I9CiSe/1, and "try-this-or-that" is the only approach we can use now, but note it makes little sense on SO, where we want to build a F&Q base of clear reusable questions and answers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm relatively new here. I'll try my best to abide by the rules next time. Thanks for understanding, and your answer there is all I (and a lot of people) need anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)\h*)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})|\d{4})(?:\W*\d{3})?\W*\d{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I9CiSe/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:(?:(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)\h*)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})|\d{4})`:

  - `(?:(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)\h*)?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)` - an optional `+` and then `234` optionall followed with a horizontal whitespace and `1`, or `01`
    - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})|` - `(`, three digits, `)` or three digits, or
  - `\d{4}`  - four digits
- `(?:\W*\d{3})?` - an optional sequence of zero or more non-word chars and then 3 digits
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `$` - end of the string.

To match the phone numbers anywhere in a longer string use

```php
(?:(?:(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)\h*)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})|\d{4})(?:\W*\d{3})?\W*\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I9CiSe/3).

Comment: When I remove the `^` start and `$` end flags in an attempt to match anywhere as opposed exact match, it trims `99999999999` 1 number from the right, e.g. now matches `9999999999` instead, which is wrong.. @Wiktor

Comment: @user627341 You can't just throw away anchors. See the bottom of my answer for a version that will work with inline matches.

Comment: Works only when numbers are separated by spaces. Is it possible to have it match anywhere, regardless of what character surrounds it.. just like in my first comment above? E.g. `99999999999fwaefdfs234(999)999-9999` should both match. I plan to use it on PHP's `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: @user627341 But certainly not when they are part of another number, right? Use `(?:(?:(?:\+?234(?:\h1)?|01)\h*)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})|\d{4})(?:\W*\d{3})?\W*\d{4}(?!\d)`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With something as simple as:

```
$output = trim(filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT), '+');
```

You will only be left with digits. Now you might want to remove several optional starts:

```
$output = preg_replace('/^0|^01|^234|^2341/', '', $input);
```

And finally you may want to check if the length is valid.

This does not invalidate a number like '+234(123) (456) 7890', but should it? After all, you can only dial numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the fresh perspective. Very much appreciated. Although I had  written something similar to what you wrote already. Was just taking on the challenge to see if I could have a universal expression for it. Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. I kept it simple.